# How to get code analysis report in VS 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I am using VS Professional 2012. I ran code analysis on the solution. I fixed some of the warning messages and suppressed some of them. Now I want the report of this code analysis report. The report should say that the no warning messages are there and the list of suppressed warning messages.

How to get such report? Is there any way out for this? Or do I nee to use any external tool? I so please suggest me.

I have fixed the warnings and have suppressed some of them. All the suppressed warnings are in the file 'GlobalSuppressions.cs'. Because of this when I run the code analysis I didn't get any warning so I can't do the copy paste. I get the warning messages in

```
'GlobalSuppression.cs' as "[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1303:Do not pass literals as localized parameters", MessageId = "System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(System.String,System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType)", Scope = "member", Target = "NonRailEngine.WindowsService.NonRailEngineService.#OnStart(System.String[])")]"
```

I was looking if this information could get in the report format after running the code analysis

Answer (score 5):

In the Code Analysis window, where it shows the results after checking out your project, if you click on any of them to expand them with details and then just `CTRL+A` to select all then `CTRL+C` to copy them to the clipboard, you can drop them into an excel file easily with a paste `CTRL+V`.

If you only want warnings for instance, then just use the filter on the top right of the results window (usually starts with the "All Results" option as default)

Comment: I have added my comment by editing the question. May be this will clear my requirement.